# Trying to Create a Shell Script Running a Python Script using wget

Tags: python, bash, shell, wget

I am trying to call an API once a day and save the data in the json using Python and convert it into a csv file.

I am using the wget library to download the file.
Even though I installed wget correctly and am able to use it in the Python Shell, I cannot run the script in bash since I get the error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named wget
```

How can I install wget on bash?
Perhaps there is a built-in library that I could use instead?

My code using wget is:

```
import wget

file_url = 'http://api-website'
file_name = wget.download(file_url)
```

Comment: You might need to install the wget python module using pip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download `wget` form **[this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget)** link and install with this commands :

Extract Wget

```
$ cd /tmp/wget
$ gzip -dc < wget-2.2.tar.gz | tar -xf -
$ cd wget-2.2
```

Build Wget

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr
$ make
```

Install Wget (must be root user)

```
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: I am using cygwin, so I don't think either of these commands apply.